# CPU invokes an action even though the same thread is stuck on modal window?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, modal-dialog, begininvoke

### Problem:

`BeginInvoke` executes code on main thread while this thread is also stuck on a modal window.

### The code: [Attached below]

- I have a button that its "Click" opens the `FolderBrowserDialog` window
- I have fileWatcherSystem to watch for a file.
- "onChanged" method is the method that being called when the file is changed. [it is called on another thread]
- In "onChanged" I use beginInvoke to call a function on the main UI thread, this function shows a messageBox.

### The flow:

1. When application starts, it starts watching a certain file using the `FileSystemWatcher` class
2. Later, the users clicks on the button and the application opens the "`FolderBrowserDialog`" window (this window is modal)
3. While the `FolderBrowserDialog`" window is still open (modal), the user changes the watched file using external editor [notepad for example]
4. The OnChanged callback is called and executes `System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke (new Action(() => showMsg()));` to call showMsg on the main thread that is still stuck on a modal dialog.

### The problem:

showMsg is called on the main thread although it is still stuck on `FolderBrowserDialog` which is still open and modal.

### Question:

Why showMsg is called immediately and not after `FolderBrowserDialog` is closed (after user will pick a folder) ?  I want showMsg to be called when the modal dialog is closed.

*Any idea will be appreciated, thanks alot!!*

### MainWindow.CS

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int threadIDMain = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        CreateFileWatcher(@"C:\temp", @"myFile.txt"); // directory path + file name
    }

    private FileSystemWatcher Watcher; 

    public void CreateFileWatcher(string directoryPath, string fileName)
    {
        Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        Watcher.Path = directoryPath;
        Watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        Watcher.Filter = fileName;
        Watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) // called when the watched file is changed , this is called on a different thread
    {
        int threadIDChanged = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => showMsg())); // calling "showMsg" on main thread
    }

    private void showMsg()
    {
        int threadIDshowMsg = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        MessageBox.Show("showMsg: Here I am in thread ID: " + threadIDshowMsg); // same thread as main thread
    }


    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            int threadIDClick = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

            dlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
            dlg.Description = "Opened from thread Id " + threadIDClick;
            System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult resultFileDialog = dlg.ShowDialog();
            if (resultFileDialog == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //handle this.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### XAML :

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="click to open file browser dialog" Height="50"  Click="Button_Click_1"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You just have the wrong mental model of what ShowDialog() is intended to do.  It solves [re-entrancy problems](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5183623/17034) by disabling the user interface, the thread most certainly is not stuck.  You'll simply have to avoid using a message box.